# Difference between SimpleChange and SimpleChanges

Tags: angular, angular5

There are two terms in angular 5  [SimpleChange](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange)
 and [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges), I didn't understand clearly from the official document could someone please explain me ??/

Comment: `SimpleChanges` is an indexed list of `SimpleChange`'s, there's not much more to it. Some API parts use the former, some use the latter, depending on whether there are several of them or not.

Answer (score 9):

`SimpleChange` class represents a basic change from a previous to new value.

It has following properties.

`previousValue`: Keeps previous value of input property.

`currentValue`: Keeps current value of input property.

`isFirstChange()`: Boolean value that tells whether the new value is the first value assigned.

https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange

`SimpleChanges` is the interface that represents all input changes as object for a component. `SimpleChanges` has the key as input property names and values are the instances of `SimpleChange` class.

```
e.g: 
@input() id: number;
@input() name: string;
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes);
}
// Output
{id: SimpleChange, name: SimpleChange}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges

Source: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleChange` is a class which is used as a type of all the properties in `SimpleChanges` interface.

```
class SimpleChange {
    previousValue: any;
    currentValue: any;
    firstChange: boolean;

    constructor(previousValue: any, currentValue: any, firstChange: boolean)

    isFirstChange(): boolean

}

interface SimpleChanges {
    __index(propName: string): SimpleChange
}
```